# Sandwich image between two paragraphs in fixed height container

Tags: html, css, layout

I need help on something from my personal project and I would appreciate any help.
I have a fixed sized container which should look something like this:
[Image sandwhiched between two texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V96S1.jpg)

Basically, I would want **Text 1** and **Text 2** to be the height of their content and **Image** to take up the rest of the height. I tried (among many other things) to set the parent container as a flexbox and giving the image a flex-basis of 0 and flex-grow of 1 but this results in a extremely thin image. All other attempts resulted in the image overflowing the container and **Text 2** being pushed out as well.

Any idea of how to achieve what it is I want to do?

Comment: I did attempt to code this for myself Paulie. I commented on this above and it truly is the extent of the attempt that brought me the closest to the solution: setting a container as flex and the image with a flex-basis of 0 and flex-grow of 1.
As for the research: I have done plenty. I've been working on this issue since yesterday.
There are no other keywords I can provide Google to make myself understood so it is time for me to seek human help.
Nevertheless, I will edit my comment and include code to make my issue more understandable.

Comment: You have to **demonstrate** what you have tried in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is made by applying to `container`:

```css
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-flow:column;
```

and then apply `flex:1` to `img-container` to stretch for the whole height of the main container.

### DEMO

```css
.container{
  height: 1200px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow:column;
}
.img-container{
  flex:1;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.img-container img{
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at dolor pulvinar erat vehicula vulputate imperdiet quis massa. Morbi dignissim consequat erat rutrum fringilla. Aenean blandit, ante quis ultricies dapibus, enim massa gravida neque, non ultrices nulla sem ac nisi. Nunc sodales dapibus libero sagittis pulvinar. Vestibulum dignissim ex leo, vel hendrerit eros mollis eget. Fusce blandit tempus orci, in bibendum libero pellentesque at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam quis ultricies lorem. Duis vehicula, nisi et pellentesque sodales, turpis arcu lacinia dolor, sit amet iaculis eros nisi a ligula. Ut id consequat nisi. Suspendisse at arcu blandit, aliquet ex dictum, finibus justo. Maecenas ac sollicitudin urna, ut luctus mi. Duis laoreet risus vitae metus accumsan volutpat.</p>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at dolor pulvinar erat vehicula vulputate imperdiet quis massa. Morbi dignissim consequat erat rutrum fringilla. Aenean blandit, ante quis ultricies dapibus, enim massa gravida neque, non ultrices nulla sem ac nisi. Nunc sodales dapibus libero sagittis pulvinar. Vestibulum dignissim ex leo, vel hendrerit eros mollis eget. Fusce blandit tempus orci, in bibendum libero pellentesque at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam quis ultricies lorem. Duis vehicula, nisi et pellentesque sodales, turpis arcu lacinia dolor, sit amet iaculis eros nisi a ligula. Ut id consequat nisi. Suspendisse at arcu blandit, aliquet ex dictum, finibus justo. Maecenas ac sollicitudin urna, ut luctus mi. Duis laoreet risus vitae metus accumsan volutpat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! overflow hidden was what was missing from me. I didn't need to use position relative for the container or absolute for the image and it still worked. Thank you very much!
EDIT: come to think of it, I find it weird that the image container refuses to comply to flex: 1 unless it has overflow hidden.

Comment: Glad it help, just need to set it as solved :)